# difference in relative position of mouse cursor focus and flash component on the latest flash player version 11.6 on chrome browser

Tags: flash, flex4, salesforce

On chromer browser with the latest flash player version installed(11.6), there seems relative postioning difference between mouse cursor and flash component(say a flash component check box is placed and its not getting selected when click made on any point on the checkbox. need to hover the checkbox to identify the focus obtained and then click to be made to get checked).

Is there any flex solution or its problem with latest flash version?

Comment: I verfied in the latest chrome version with latest flash player(11.6), right side corner of the mouse cursor is attaining the focus instead of the cursor tool tip. Is there any work around from flex end to resolve the issue. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the bug where the padding attribute in the VF page doesn't support on chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, that what i did (try it)
1. Go to **chrome://plugins/**
2. There is probably **Shockwave Flash** plugin that disabled, enable it.
try to check that, hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks kortize. Later on identified the exact issue.